# spacy how do I get a list of words with some white space exception?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to get a list having words but for some word I want them to be a single entity instead of two separate entities.

For example,

If my text is like

text = 'olive oil is one of the common ingredients and bell pepper is also quite common'

//desired output is

['olive oil', 'is','one','of','the','common','ingredients','and','bell pepper','is','also' 'quite','common']

I had look into PhraseMatcher but phrasematcher detect a certain phrase as a match but doesn't give me the final out come I desire above.

It would be perfect if I could set a logic like [{'POS': 'NOUN'}, {'lower':'oil}]
which let me get any two-combination ending with 'oil' as a single element
like 'xxx oil', 'yyy oil', 'abc oil'.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem with sample?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over here, assuming you have a dict of all words that are supposed to be part of the ending of a noun, you can use this.
I assumed by lower you mean the ending of a word. You can use a similar implementation for the starting key of a word.

```
text = 'olive oil is one of the common ingredients and bell pepper is also quite common'

word_index = {
    'oil': 'lower',
    'pepper': 'lower'
}

def change_text(some_text):
    process = some_text.split()
    i = 0
    while i<len(process):
        if process[i] in word_index:
            if word_index[process[i]] == 'lower':
                process[i-1:i+1] = [f'{process[i-1]} {process[i]}']
        i+=1
    return process
```

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit but really really helpful. Thank you